# javax.net.ssl.SSLException: hostname in certificate didn't match in Android

Tags: android, web-services, ssl, https

I am updating the web service URL of the android application, we are using `https` protocol. I see that my current https URL is working but now we are migrating to new domain then it is creating problem.

I have checked many threads on stackoverflow like [javax.net.ssl.SSLException: hostname in certificate didn't match android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25356739/javax-net-ssl-sslexception-hostname-in-certificate-didnt-match-android) but didn't find any good answer mostly are answering bypass this security or allow all.

> javax.net.ssl.SSLException: hostname in certificate didn't match:

```
//HttpGet getMethod = new HttpGet(String.format(httpURL));
HttpGet getMethod = new HttpGet(httpURL);
DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
HttpParams params = client.getParams();
params.setParameter(CoreConnectionPNames.CONNECTION_TIMEOUT, 60000);
params.setParameter(CoreConnectionPNames.SO_TIMEOUT, 60000);
client.setParams(params);
responseBody = client.execute(getMethod, responseHandler);
responseBody = responseBody.trim();
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you try the same url in browser and did you get any certificate errors??

Comment: @Panther No error, it is working in browser

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If it works in the browser but not in the app it might be a problem with missing SNI support, see  [Why does android get the wrong ssl certificate? (two domains, one server)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21956663/why-does-android-get-the-wrong-ssl-certificate-two-domains-one-server).

Comment: Yes it is working in the browser not in the app. Do we have to keep some certificate also in the app also for this ssl connection ?

Comment: No, you have to use something which supports SNI or you have to have a separate IP address for the HTTPS server, so that you don't need to use SNI. See the linked question for more details.

Answer (score 7):

It seems that the best solution to this is to use HttpsUrlConnection instead of HttpGet.

```
URL url = new Url(httpURL);
HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
urlConnection.setReadTimeout(60000);
urlConnection.setConnectTimeout(60000);
urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
urlConnection.setDoInput(true);

urlConnection.connect();
```

Then use InputStream to get the response body.

```
InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
```

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to [Make HTTPS / HTTP Request in Android](http://tutorialsface.blogspot.com/2014/07/make-https-http-request-in-android.html)

Add a Java class **CustomSSLSocketFactory.java**

```
 import java.io.IOException;
 import java.net.Socket;
 import java.net.UnknownHostException;
 import java.security.KeyManagementException;
 import java.security.KeyStore;
 import java.security.KeyStoreException;
 import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
 import java.security.UnrecoverableKeyException;
 import java.security.cert.CertificateException;
 import java.security.cert.X509Certificate;
 import javax.net.ssl.SSLContext;
 import javax.net.ssl.TrustManager;
 import javax.net.ssl.X509TrustManager;
 import org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory;

 public class CustomSSLSocketFactory extends SSLSocketFactory{
SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
/**
 * Generate Certificate for ssl connection
 * @param truststore
 * @throws NoSuchAlgorithmException
 * @throws KeyManagementException
 * @throws KeyStoreException
 * @throws UnrecoverableKeyException
 */
public CustomSSLSocketFactory(KeyStore truststore)
        throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, KeyManagementException,
        KeyStoreException, UnrecoverableKeyException {
    super(truststore);
    TrustManager tm = new X509TrustManager(){
        @Override
        public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] arg0, String arg1)
                throws CertificateException {
        }
        @Override
        public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain,
                                       String authType) throws CertificateException {
        }
        @Override
        public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
            return null;
        }
    };
    sslContext.init(null, new TrustManager[] {tm}, null);
}

@Override
public Socket createSocket(Socket socket, String host, int port,
                           boolean autoClose) throws IOException, UnknownHostException {
    return sslContext.getSocketFactory().createSocket(socket, host, port,
            autoClose);
}

@Override
public Socket createSocket() throws IOException {
    return sslContext.getSocketFactory().createSocket();
}
 }
```

in your code

```
    String cloud_url="https://www.google.com";
    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        if(cloud_url.toLowerCase().contains("https://")){
            KeyStore trustStore = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
            trustStore.load(null, null);
            SSLSocketFactory sf = new CustomSSLSocketFactory(trustStore);
            sf.setHostnameVerifier(SSLSocketFactory.ALLOW_ALL_HOSTNAME_VERIFIER);

            HttpParams params = new BasicHttpParams();
            SchemeRegistry registry = new SchemeRegistry();
            registry.register(new Scheme("https", sf, 443));

            ClientConnectionManager ccm = new ThreadSafeClientConnManager(params, registry);
            client= new DefaultHttpClient(ccm, params);
        }


        HttpGet request= new HttpGet( );
        request.setURI(new URI( cloud_url));
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
```